# How to restrict edit only on data display in the index in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my edit.blade.php. In the show view, I have restricted it only on the users' logged in  as you can see in my controller

```
 public function index()
    {
        $animal = Auth::user()->animals;
        return view('farms.index', compact('animal'));
    }
```

And my index view

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Farm Dashboard</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        @if (session('status'))
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                {{ session('status') }}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        You are logged in! {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                            <br>
                        <a href="farms/create">Add animal</a>

                            @foreach( $animal as $animal)
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-2">{{ $animal->id }}</div>
                                    <div class="col-4"><a href="/farms/{{ $animal->id }}">{{ $animal->type->category }}</a></div>
                                    <div class="col-4">{{ $animal->created_at }}</div>
                                </div>
                            @endforeach


                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

But I still have a problem if I change in my url the id number of an object of another user I can still edit and update.

What can I change in my controller to prevent that

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $animal = Animal::query()->findOrFail($id);
        return view('farms.show', compact('animal'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $type = Type::all();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $animal = Animal::query()->findOrFail($id);

        return view('farms.edit', compact('animal', 'type', 'user'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param $id
     * @return void
     */
    public function update($id)
    {
        $animal = Animal::query()->findOrFail($id);
        $animal->update($this->validateRequest());

        return redirect('farms/' . $animal->id)->with('message', 'Animal Details Updated');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this basic/easy method

For Show

```
public function show($id)
{
   try {
      $user = auth()->user();
      $animal = Animal::where('user_id', $user->id)->findOrFail($id);
      return view('farms.show', compact('animal'));
   } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      //return exception or any other page
      abort(404, 'Not allowed');
      //or return back()->withErrors(['Not allowed']);
   }
}
```

For edit

```
public function edit($id)
{
   try {
     $type = Type::all();
     $user = auth()->user();
     $animal = Animal::where('user_id', $user->id)->findOrFail($id);

     return view('farms.edit', compact('animal', 'type', 'user'));
   } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      //return exception or any other page
   }

}
```

For update

```
public function update($id)
{
   try {
     $user = auth()->user();
     $animal = Animal::where('user_id', $user->id)->findOrFail($id);
     $animal->update($this->validateRequest());

     return redirect('farms/' . $animal->id)->with('message', 'Animal Details Updated'); //use route for redirect instead of url
   } catch(\Exception $ex) {
      //return exception or any other page
   }
}
```

Use `try catch` for exception

Make sure you defined that animal has `user_id`

or

You can also manage this functionality with relationship
[Larave Eloquent relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

For standard practice, you can use laravel gate policy
[Laravel policy via model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authorization#via-the-user-model)

Comment: This is the error I am getting "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function findOrFail() on null"

Comment: use try catch block to handle exception

Comment: I am sorry am still new to laravel so I don;t know how to use catch block to handle errors in laravel

Comment: your error seems like you are trying to access something on null object. Take a look once again it should work. if not share your code here or in chat